# Python - How to send a value through a request param or other way around

Tags: python, class, request

So basically I am trying to do something that I am not aware if it will work or not at all. I have tried it but of course it wont work. My plan is to send a value with ****kwargs** where I then later can use it through another class which takes care of the value.

Etc:

```
from my_requests_class import request_method

send_to_request = request_method()

value_to_send = "Hello stackoverflow"
def send():
    while True:

        try:
            url = 'https://www.google.com'


            headers = {
                'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36'
                               ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36')
            }

            resp = send_to_request.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False, timeout=12, text=value_to_send)
            resp.raise_for_status()


        except HTTPError as err:
            randomtime = random.randint(0, 1)
            print("Woopsi, couldn't send!")
            time.sleep(randomtime)
            continue
```

and this is my second class:

```
class request_method(Session):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Session.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


    def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):

        resp = Session.request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs)        
        print(value_to_send)
```

however if I run this sort of code I will get

```
request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

meaning I can't add a value to requests() - so my question for you is that how can I be able to send the **value_to_send** to the method which is in another class `def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):` ? so that I can in that case print

```
def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):

    resp = Session.request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs)        
    print(value_to_send)
    return resp
```

Comment: how are you going to send the `value_to_send`? in the request body?

Comment: @HenryWoody Hey Henry! Well Im not sure. It doesn't need to be in the request body - I wasn't sure if it was possible to do it either but I thought maybe that could be sort of idea?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do what you want to do, I'm just trying to get a better sense of the problem. Can you included the code for the method `my_requests_class.get`?

Comment: @HenryWoody Woopsi! I just added it now. I edited the code so it should be all good now.

Comment: oh that looks better, but can you include the code for `request_method.get`? I assume it's a wrapper for `request_method.request`, but it would be good to see

Comment: I have changed it abit now but Im not sure if I understood your question. Basically it goes to the `class request_method(Session):` and then to the `def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):` basically. @HenryWoody - if this was the thing you were wondering?

Comment: In the first code block you have the line `resp = send_to_request.get(url, ...`, which I assume is causing the error, but I don't see where you have defined `send_to_request.get`, or is it just supposed to be `send_to_request.request()`?

Comment: I defined the send_to:request at the the top `send_to_request = request_method()` which call the other class which later than goes into `def request` but if I understand your question is should be something similar as if I just did `request.get(url...)` but instead I send it to a class which does almost the same. @HenryWoody

Comment: the issue is that you call the `get` method of the `request_method` class, but you have not shown the code for this `get` method

Comment: Oh hmm! That is a good question. Well I didn't thought about it until you said it now. But I think the get method is taken from the requests package which includes the get whenever you use the `request` - I just havent actually thought about it since it actually works without the question I am looking for here. (Without sending a value to another class) @HenryWoody

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you pass all given `kwargs` from your custom request method directly to `Session.request`. You can still pass additional keyword arguments to your custom method, but you have to be sure not to pass invalid keyword args to `Session.request`.

You can do this by calling `pop` on `kwargs` to retrieve and remove special keyword arguments that you'd like to pass to your custom method, but not on to `Session.request`.

For example:

```
class RequestMethod(Session):
    def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
        text = kwargs.pop("text", "")
        resp = Session.request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now `text` has the value passed in as a keyword argument, in your example `"Hello stackoverflow"`, and is no longer included in `kwargs`.